# R: Two dimensional non-parametric regression

Tags: r, statistics

What packages and functions in R can perform a two dimensional non-additive local regression/smooth.  For example consider

```
b<-seq(-6*pi,6*pi,length=100)
xy<-expand.grid(b,b) 
x=xy[[1]]
y=xy[[2]]
z= sin(x)+cos(y) + 2*sin(x)*cos(y)
contour(b,b,matrix(z,100,100))
```

[image]

What functions could estimate this?

Comment: OK now a little more complicated how do I do in in an additive, binary framework?

Comment: You may also try on stats.stackexchange.com

Comment: Doing this with binary data could be a little tricky.  Two things I can think of: (1) do loess anyway; use bootstrap to get confidence intervals (a little tricky because of the spatial aspect -- block bootstrap?) or (2) use gam() in mgcv (but see @ucfagls's comment below for difficulties with this approach)

Comment: PS perhaps you could also try some sort of Fourier or wavelet transform/smooth

Comment: I'm looking at the locfit package for doing local likelihood in an additive model, but keep getting errors.  I might have to do loess despite the binary nature.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can do this with loess:

```
fit <- loess( z ~ x+ y, span=0.01 )
dev.new()

contour( b, b, matrix( predict(fit), 100, 100 ) )
```

Answer (score 1):

mgcv has a variety of 2-D spline options.

Comment: That was going to be my suggestion after I saw Greg's answer. However, when I tried this I needed to fit a very complex surface using a large number of knots and even then, the fit was not as good as the `loess()` one in this case. I used something like `gam( z ~ s(x, y, k = 200)` to get a reasonable fit. I didn't explore much further as my old laptop wasn't up to the task of fitting these models quickly.